# perlomni.vim installation fail using pathogen or vundle

Tags: vim, plugins, pathogen, ftplugin, vundle

I am tyring to install perlomni.vim so I can use auto function lookup in a gvim window.

I have tried using pathhogen and vundle for trying to configure this bundle.

I think the problem I am running into is how I am install perlomni.vim

I have a directory set up ~/.vim/bundle/vundle and ~/.vim/bundle

PATHOGEN WAY

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/c9s/perlomni.vim.git
cd perlomni.v
make install
```

Then since I am running in tcsh shell I set the path variable as 
    set path=($path\:$home/.vim/bin)

Should I be trying to install this undle the .vim/bundle directory.....when I run the make install command it tries to install it into the .vim/ directory and place all the .vim files it uses into .vim/ftplugin .vim/plugin .vim/bin directory.......So maybe I do not have the other right settings in my .vimrc file to include the bundle installed this way.

VUNDLE WAY
I have vundle installed and here is a snippet of my .vimrc

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

call pathogen#incubate()
execute pathogen#infect()

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

"Required Bundel Statement
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

"User Installed Bundles
Bundle 'neocomplcache/neocomplcache.vim'
Bundle 'perlomni/perlomni.vim'

" Non Git Hub Bundles
"Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" Bundles on Local Machine
Bundle '/usr/share/vim/vim70/ftplugin/perl.vim'

filetype plugin indent on
filetype on
syntax on
```

Comment: You forgot to mention: what doesn't work?

Comment: The installation did not work. When I open up a gvim window with my perl classes and scipts perlomni.vim is not working with them.

Comment: "It does not work." doesn't say much. How does the installation fail? Is the script not loaded? Is there an error? What happens when you press `CTRL-X CTRL-O`? We can't help you if you don't say what's wrong.

Comment: The script is not loading......when I hit CTRL-X it goes into x mode and thats it....in CTRL-O nothing happens.....

Comment: @user2479059 it says in the README that if you use pathogen you don't need to do a `make install. And the plugin works for me after doing the clone.

Comment: So I have it installed except when I try to use CTRL-X CTRL-O I get the error omnifunc is not set

Comment: @user2479059 whats the output of `set ft?` when you are in the file you are trying to edit.

Comment: .....it says filetype perl

Answer (score 0):

With this vimrc, pathogen, and perlomni.vim in the bundle directory `<C-X><C-O>` preforms omnicompletion.

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

call pathogen#infect()
```

Without seeing your actual vimrc I do not know what the problem is but this works for me.

Comment: how did you set your omnifunc variable for it?

Comment: @user2479059 I didn't the plugin set it for me.

Comment: I keep getting the error....omnifunc not set when I go to try to use perlomni.vim

Comment: @user2479059 Well I have no idea. Wait for someone else I guess

Comment: Here is my vim rc `set nocompatible
filetype off


call pathogen#incubate()
call pathogen#infect()


set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

"Required Bundel Statement
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'


"User Installed Bundles
Bundle 'neocomplcache/neocomplcache.vim'
Bundle 'perlomni.vim'


" Non Git Hub Bundles
"Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" Bundles on Local Machine
Bundle '/usr/share/vim/vim70/ftplugin/perl.vim'



filetype plugin indent on
filetype on
syntax on



let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1`

Comment: @user2479059 do you really have pathogen and vundle in there at the same time? I can't believe they would play nicely with each other

Comment: I took out Vunlde and it seemed to work better except it couldnt find any matches or any of my class functions